# Getting a Value in the First index of a TableAdapter in C#

Tags: c#, tableadapter

Am trying to get a a `Zero indexed Value` from a column  in the TableAdpter but it has refused , how can i retrieve a value in the **Column index Zero** , below is my code :

```
LoginTableAdapter l = new LoginTableAdapter();
string res = l.GetData("mueat", "1234").Rows[0].ToString();
```

And my  table which is attached to the `TableAdapter` is as below , it's one column and i want to get the value **t** *which is in a Zero index*  in the column **access**:

[image]

Comment: _"but it has refused"_ - exactly what does this mean - do you get an exception thrown or another error - if so please give full details.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume `l.GetData("mueat", "1234")` returns a [DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx), like so:

```
DataTable table = l.GetData("mueat", "1234"); // the dataTable
```

then this:

```
DataRow row = table.Rows[0];  // first row;
```

will only give you the first row out of the [DataRowCollection's indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.item(v=vs.110).aspx)

As we can see on the [DataRow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow(v=vs.110).aspx) type, it has an [indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.item(v=vs.110).aspx) as well, giving access to the columns in the DataRow instance.

```
object columnValue = row[0]; // first column
```

You can now cast the object value to the correct type or call `ToString` on it to convert it to its string representation.

Putting this all back together in your compact one-liner you will get:

```
string res = l.GetData("mueat", "1234").Rows[0][0].ToString();
```